# Set a breakpoint inside a library jar in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to set a breakpoint inside a method from a 3rd party library added to my Griffon project. During debug, the breakpoint becomes marked with an X, with the tooltip informing me that "no executable code was found". I've also tried setting the breakpoint just before the method call in my source and stepping in, but this failed to step into the library source as well.

I have the library attached as jar with a source directory and set to export in Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies. I am using IntelliJ 11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot set Java breakpoint in Intellij IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591662/cannot-set-java-breakpoint-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Some types of lines you can't set a break point on.

Answer (score 6):

Clicking in the margin of the opened source editor seems to work for me. It didn't the first time I tried though. A restart seemed to clear it up.

Comment: A restart didn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959163/breakpoints-inside-speechrecognizer-java-are-ignored