# no executable code found at line intellij 14

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, tomcat8, intellij-14

I am unable to debug remote applications due to: No executable code at line

I am running ultimate edition of Intellij, version 14.0.3. My application is running inside tomcat 8 and i'm building it from the command line using Maven. This problem appeared after i switched from the community edition to the ultimate edition.

Project sources are the same and I am able to connect to tomcat for remote debugging. The only issue is that all my breakpoints are invalidated.

Please advice on how to fix this issue.

Cheers.

Comment: Perhaps you need to invalidate caches, restart, recompile, redeploy.

Comment: already done all of them :(

Comment: I did all the steps, but it didn't work. Finally, I tried running -> mvn clean install and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set Java breakpoint in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591662/cannot-set-java-breakpoint-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all IDEA related project files and open the project by the .pom file.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. Simply compile the directory that the class resides, and the debugger will pick up the break point.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is much more embarrassing. I put the breakpoint on the wrong line.

[image]

You see two breakpoints, first one is working and the second one is complaining about "no executable code ...".

It turns out there really is no executable code, just a string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I implemented a similar solution.

> Remove all IDEA related project files and open the project by the .pom file.

I use Gradle for my projecto, so i removed the project from intellij and then reimported it.

I hope others could read it and helps them

Comment: Also on gradle… worked for me: open the Gradle panel and "Reload all gradle projects"

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing an Atlassian plug-in and connected to the server via remote debug, run `atlas-package` to sync deployed plug-in and your source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a maven project execute the following commands in cmd prompt.

mvn clean install

mvn compile

This will resolve the problem.