# Cannot debug a CustomView in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-custom-view

I cannot debug a custom view. "No executable code found at line" message shown. Also on a MainActivity the debug works fine and stop on `setText` method, but in my custom view not. The debug cannot in to my custom view method. And on the other methods did not stop, like `onDraw`.
How can I fix it?

I have tried to clean, rebuild and restart project. Instant run is disabled. The Android Studio 3.4.1 version.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val pipsTextView = findViewById<PipsTextView>(R.id.pips_text_view)
        pipsTextView.setText("1123.23444", 5, 2, 3, -1)
    }
}

override fun setText(value: String, pipSize: Int, prePipSize: Int, floatingPipSize: Int, direction: Int) {
        this.pipSize = pipSize
        this.prePipSize = prePipSize
        this.floatingPipSize = floatingPipSize
        this.direction = if (direction < 0) DOWN else if (direction == 0) NEUTRAL else UP
        preparePipValues(value)
        invalidate()
    }
```

I expect the debug will work.

Comment: you setup a breakpoint in `setText` and it stops there? so if it doesnt stop in your custom view method it means that it is not called

Comment: No the `setText` is called. I cannot fix it properly, but after 3th `clean and invalidate and restart -> clean -> rebuild` I got some result. Now I do not start project in Debug mode. I start and then attach the process to debug, now the debug stops in `preparePipValues(values)` method in the `setText` method. It is very strange behaviour. On the Java I never got this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591662/cannot-set-java-breakpoint-in-intellij-idea) question, the following steps may help you:

1. If you are using Maven dependencies, go to Maven Projects -> refresh
2. If that does not work, Try top menu --> Build --> Rebuild Project
3. If that still doesn't work, try top menu --> File --> Invalidate Cache/Restart
4. If that still doesn't work, then $CATALINA_BASE/bin/catalina.sh stop, then start

After this, usually it covers 99% of the problems. Otherwise, Probably you will have to examine some other possibilities.