# Breakpoints inside SpeechRecognizer.java are ignored

Tags: android, android-studio

In my attempts to troubleshoot a `android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT` error in my app, I set breakpoints in [SpeechRecognizer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java) lines that invoke my listener's `onError()`, i.e. 9 lines containing:

```
mListener.onError(ERROR_CLIENT);
```

This is because there are 9 different reasons for this error, but they are invisible to my app, and the preceding `Log.e(TAG, "cancel() failed", e);` statement is nowhere to be seen on my Debug console.

Those breakpoints, however, are **ignored**.

I know for certain that those `mListener.onError(ERROR_CLIENT);` are called, because setting a breakpoint in my app's listener's onError on

```
case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
```

works!

AFAICR, it should be possible to place a breakpoint inside a library jar. What am I missing?

Is it possible to breakpoint inside `SpeechRecognizer.java` such that it breaks when reached?

(using Android Studio **2021.3.1 Patch 1**)

In case the following brings up some insights, note the 69 errors in the original file from SDK 33:
[image: 69 errors in the original file from SDK 33]

They are mainly due to unresolved symbols:
[image: mainly due to unresolved symbols]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some more experimentation, I discovered that placing a breakpoint inside `SpeechRecognizer.java` **does break** when reached:

[image: Breakpoints inside a library jar do work]

I did that by going down the stacktrace:

[image: SpeechRecognizer error stacktrace]

This tells me that the elusive `Log.e(TAG, "cancel() failed", e);` perhaps **never gets called**. But that is a different issue.

In the meanwhile, it looks like the only way to tell **which of the 9** candidates for ERROR_CLIENT is the root cause, would be to spot and track the stacktrace thrown by a [NetworkSpeechRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74992543/2597758) exception:

```
W  Recognizer network error 
    at com.google.android.apps.speech.tts.googletts.service.GoogleTTSRecognitionService.onCancel(PG:6)
    at android.speech.RecognitionService.dispatchCancel(RecognitionService.java:185)
    at android.speech.RecognitionService.-$$Nest$mdispatchCancel(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.speech.RecognitionService$1.handleMessage(RecognitionService.java:110)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```