# NetworkSpeechRecognize vs SodaSpeechRecognizer

Tags: android-speech-api

In my attempts to troubleshoot a challenging SpeechRecognizer.java issue, I noticed in Logcat messages TAGs that are not SpeechRecognizer's:

```
12:34:00.933 NetworkSpeechRecognizer          pid-29210  I  Online recognizer - start listening
12:34:00.936 SodaSpeechRecognizer             pid-29210  I  Offline recognizer - start listening
12:34:00.936 SodaSpeechRecognizer                        I  Initialize Soda [locale: en-US]
12:34:00.963 SodaSpeechRecognizer                        I  Initialize Soda with language pack directory
12:34:01.099 SodaSpeechRecognizer                        I  Offline recognizer - start detection
12:34:02.975 NetworkSpeechRecognizer                     I  #cancel
12:34:02.976 NetworkSpeechRecognizer          pid-29210  I  #cancel
12:34:02.976 NetworkSpeechRecognizer                     I  #failWithException
12:34:02.977 SodaSpeechRecognizer                        I  startDetection successful
12:34:02.979 NetworkSpeechRecognizer                     W  Recognizer network error
12:34:02.979 SodaSpeechRecognizer                        I  Offline recognizer - stop detection
```

- What is `SodaSpeechRecognizer`?
- Where can I learn more about it?
- How are these tags generated if SpeechRecognizer.java only defines:

  `private static final String TAG = "SpeechRecognizer";`

**Update:** I just found this article [SODA: Speech On-Device API](https://hackaday.io/project/164399-android-offline-speech-recognition-natively-on-pc) along with [this page](https://hackaday.io/project/164399-android-offline-speech-recognition-natively-on-pc/log/176945-soda-speech-on-device-api). Nice clue, but insufficient as this is not official documentation.

The following official documentation from Google seems to be much better: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/priv/docs/ondevice-overview

Yet, it is still mysterious, quoting:

> This product is a private feature. The documentation is publicly
> available but you must contact Google for full access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to answer my questions (until a better answer comes along):

1. `SodaSpeechRecognizer` is the on-device speech recognizer (SODA is an acronym for "Speech On-Device API"). It is unclear yet when it was [introduced](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/speech-on-device-run-server-quality-speech-ai-locally). Could this be with the introduction of `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`(Android 4.1 AKA "Jelly Bean", released in June 2012)?
2. The best way to learn about it is at https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/priv/docs/ondevice-overview . One must contact Google for full access, though.
3. Those tags were likely defined in a `C++` module name `soda_async_impl.cc`, as it is the only one visible on Logcat that produces SODA related messages:

```
native                    W  W0206 12:01:28.459973   32167 soda_async_impl.cc:320] Creating soda_impl.
                          W  W0206 12:01:28.460534   32167 soda_async_impl.cc:322] Created with thread priority 10
native                    W  W0206 12:01:29.632099   32167 soda_async_impl.cc:484] SODA session starting (require_hotword:0, hotword_timeout_in_millis:0, trigger_type:TRIGGER_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED, hybrid_asr_config.mode:MODE_DEFAULT)
native                    W  W0206 12:01:29.634873   32200 soda_async_impl.cc:1203] SODA received first mic audio buffer, size in bytes: 320, format: 1, channels: 1, : sample rate: 16000
native                    W  W0206 12:01:30.154026   32200 soda_async_impl.cc:959] Not receiving any loopback audio in 500ms. Last audio received time: 0, Current time in us: 1675677690154022
native                    W  W0206 12:01:33.162399   32200 soda_async_impl.cc:861] SODA stopped processing audio, mics audio processed in millis: 4880, loopback audio processed in millis: 0
                          W  W0206 12:01:33.265670   32200 soda_async_impl.cc:916] SODA session stopped due to: MIC_END_OF_DATA
                          W  W0206 12:01:33.319812   32171 soda_async_impl.cc:987] Deleting soda_impl
```